# Connect to Safari Web inspector via WIFI

Tags: iphone, macos, safari, web-inspector

Can we inspect a webpage in iPhone from Safari in MAC by connecting both MAC and iPhone to same network (Wifi) ? I could inspect by connecting with USB cable. But it would be more convenient over wifi as I will be able to debug remotely from a Windows machine that connects to the MAC over VNC.

Answer (score 2):

you should install Safari Technology Preview that plays the role of safari@next.

url to download safari technology preview version:
https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/

then you can debug it just like it's connected via a cable.

it's all explained in the url below:
https://silvantroxler.ch/2018/wireless-remote-debugging-with-safari-on-ios/